# Using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging 6 parameters overloaded Write Method, writing extra \r\n

Tags: c#

> Logger.Write(_indent + message, category.ToString(), 1, 100,
>   eventType, title);

**the above write method write text like so in a log file which is text file**

> 9/21/2015 10:01:49 AM | Information | Adding key in dictionary, user:
>   abc
>
> \r\n

here you can see extra \r\n which has not been provided by me in any parameter. ***I do not want these extra \r\n characters***

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is i donot want this extra \r\n when this method writes this line of text in text file

Comment: can anyone provide me valid anwer? please inform me if question needs more specific information. It is my assumption that I have already provided enough information for anyone to understand and answer, but still anyone feels the question is vague or have irrelevant information then I can provide to them if ask